# Different behavior in release and debug mode in xamarin forms app

Tags: c#, xamarin, navigation

I create an cross platform application.
when run project in debug mode and click on login button it ***work correctly***
,but when i set in ***release mode*** and click on login button get my error message
this is my Login xaml

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="30" Spacing="40">
        <BoxView HeightRequest="10"/>
        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="300" Source="maco.jpg"/>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#BF043055" HasShadow="False">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="10">
                <Entry x:Name="Email" Text="{Binding Email}" Placeholder="پست الکترونیک"   
                       PlaceholderColor="White" HeightRequest="40"   
                       Keyboard="Email"  
                       TextColor="White"/>
                <Entry x:Name="Password" Text="{Binding Password}" Placeholder="کلمه عبور"   
                       PlaceholderColor="White" HeightRequest="40"   
                       IsPassword="True"  
                       TextColor="White"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        <Button Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" Text="login" TextColor="White"  
                FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
                BackgroundColor="#088da5" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

this is my login.xaml.cs

```
 [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    public LoginPage()
    {
        var vm = new LoginViewModel( Navigation);
        this.BindingContext = vm;
        vm.DisplayInvalidLoginPrompt += () => DisplayAlert("Error", "Invalid Login, try again", "OK");
      
        InitializeComponent();

        Email.Completed += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            Password.Focus();
        };

        Password.Completed += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            vm.SubmitCommand.Execute(null);
        };
    }
}
```

i Use mvvm pattern and this is my mvvm

```
 public class LoginViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Action DisplayInvalidLoginPrompt;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    public INavigation Navigation { get; set; }
    private string email;
    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
        set
        {
            email = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Email"));
        }
    }
    private string password;
    public string Password
    {
        get { return password; }
        set
        {
            password = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Password"));
        }
    }
    public ICommand SubmitCommand { protected set; get; }
    //public LoginViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    //{
    //    SubmitCommand = new Command(OnSubmit);
    //}
    public LoginViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        this.Navigation = navigation;
        SubmitCommand = new Command(async ()=>await OnSubmitAsync());
    }
    public async Task OnSubmitAsync()
    {
        if (email != "s" || password != "s")
        {
            DisplayInvalidLoginPrompt();
        }
        else
        {
           await Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
        }
    }
```

In release mode or after install in real phone, When I type "s" and "s" (without quotation marks) it will show my error message("Invalid Login, try agai") but in debug mode it work fine.

How can I resolve that?

***Update***
this is "debug log logcat" in release

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
07-19 13:35:20.891  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   GoogleInputMethod   onFinishInput() : Dummy InputConnection bound
07-19 13:35:20.914  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 25264   Conv2QueryExtension Conv2Query not enabled due to current app [ir.sunn.emsbase] not in whitelist
07-19 13:35:20.913  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   Conv2QueryExtension Current locale: en_US, config allows these locales: de,en,fr,it,es,pt
07-19 13:35:20.912  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   Conv2QueryExtension isEnabled() : true
07-19 13:35:20.912  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   EmojiSuperpacksFeature  Emoji superpacks enabled
07-19 13:35:20.912  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   EmojiDataExtension  onActivate() : Locale = en_US
07-19 13:35:20.912  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   DevFeatureConfig    Gif candidate disabled by Phenotype
07-19 13:35:20.912  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   GifEntryExtension   onActivate()
07-19 13:35:20.905  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Debug   17925   EGL_emulation   eglMakeCurrent: 0xebc853c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xebc836f0)
07-19 13:35:20.900  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 25264   VoiceImeTranscriptor    UIME feature enabled: false
07-19 13:35:20.893  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   GoogleInputMethod   onStartInputView() : Dummy InputConnection bound
07-19 13:35:20.891  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   GoogleInputMethod   onStartInput() : Dummy InputConnection bound
07-19 13:35:20.889  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   PhenotypeExpConfig  refreshConfiguration() : Force = false : UpdateAvailable = false : Age = 62 minutes : MaxAge = 720 minutes
07-19 13:35:20.889  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   GoogleInputMethod   onFinishInputView() : Dummy InputConnection bound
07-19 13:35:20.888  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 17925   monodroid-assembly  typemap: module matching MVID [CAD0FB41-A72A-4345-B6B8-DAF8486E8A76] not found.
07-19 13:35:20.869  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25132   GnssLocationProvider    WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@bf31831)
07-19 13:35:20.868  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25132   GnssLocationProvider    WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@bf31831)
07-19 13:35:20.865  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Debug   17925   OpenGLRenderer  endAllActiveAnimators on 0xcd2ec200 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xebc83770
07-19 13:35:20.860  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Debug   17925   EGL_emulation   eglMakeCurrent: 0xebc853c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xebc836f0)
07-19 13:35:20.823  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Debug   17925   EGL_emulation   eglMakeCurrent: 0xebc853c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xebc836f0)
07-19 13:35:19.919  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 17925   monodroid-assembly  typemap: module matching MVID [CAD0FB41-A72A-4345-B6B8-DAF8486E8A76] not found.
07-19 13:35:19.892  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Debug   17925   EGL_emulation   eglMakeCurrent: 0xebc853c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xebc836f0)
07-19 13:35:19.874  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25132   GnssLocationProvider    WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@dc71dec)
07-19 13:35:19.870  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 17925   monodroid-assembly  typemap: module matching MVID [CAD0FB41-A72A-4345-B6B8-DAF8486E8A76] not found.
07-19 13:35:19.868  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Debug   17925   EGL_emulation   eglMakeCurrent: 0xebc853c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xebc836f0)
07-19 13:35:19.867  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25132   GnssLocationProvider    WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@dc71dec)
07-19 13:35:19.841  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 17925   monodroid-assembly  typemap: module matching MVID [CAD0FB41-A72A-4345-B6B8-DAF8486E8A76] not found.
07-19 13:35:19.838  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 17925   monodroid-assembly  typemap: module matching MVID [CAD0FB41-A72A-4345-B6B8-DAF8486E8A76] not found.
07-19 13:35:19.818  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Debug   17925   EGL_emulation   eglMakeCurrent: 0xebc853c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xebc836f0)
07-19 13:35:19.793  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Debug   17925   EGL_emulation   eglMakeCurrent: 0xebc853c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xebc836f0)
07-19 13:35:19.663  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Debug   1652    gralloc_ranchu  gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 3174400
07-19 13:35:19.655  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Debug   1652    gralloc_ranchu  gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 3174400
07-19 13:35:19.643  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Debug   1652    gralloc_ranchu  gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 3174400
07-19 13:35:19.583  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 17925   monodroid-assembly  typemap: module matching MVID [CAD0FB41-A72A-4345-B6B8-DAF8486E8A76] not found.
07-19 13:35:19.580  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    17925   chatty  uid=10097(ir.sunn.emsbase) identical 7 lines
07-19 13:35:19.455  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 17925   monodroid-assembly  typemap: module matching MVID [CAD0FB41-A72A-4345-B6B8-DAF8486E8A76] not found.
07-19 13:35:18.870  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25132   GnssLocationProvider    WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@46923fd)
07-19 13:35:18.868  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25132   GnssLocationProvider    WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@46923fd)
07-19 13:35:18.255  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 17925   monodroid-assembly  typemap: module matching MVID [CAD0FB41-A72A-4345-B6B8-DAF8486E8A76] not found.
07-19 13:35:18.190  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 17925   monodroid-assembly  typemap: module matching MVID [CAD0FB41-A72A-4345-B6B8-DAF8486E8A76] not found.
07-19 13:35:18.187  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   FeaturePermissions  onSharedPreferenceChanged() : Key = latest_activation_time : Feature = null
07-19 13:35:18.171  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   PrimesMetrics   Ignore memory metric of com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.libs.pill.PillExtension.
07-19 13:35:18.171  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   PrimesMetrics   Ignore memory metric of com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.libs.search.nativecard.FeatureCardNoticeExtension.
07-19 13:35:18.171  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   VoiceImeExtension   Voice Extension onStartInputView() Mic status = [MicIconAvailable]
07-19 13:35:18.171  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 25264   VoiceImeTranscriptor    UIME feature enabled: false
07-19 13:35:18.171  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   FeatureCardNotice   Feature card notice not shown: no cards to display
07-19 13:35:18.171  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   FeatureCardGenerator    Autospace card not added
07-19 13:35:18.168  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   PrimesMetrics   Ignore memory metric of com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.libs.search.gif.GifEntryPointCandidateExtension.
07-19 13:35:18.168  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   FeatureCardGenerator    Make a GIF card not added
07-19 13:35:18.168  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 25264   Conv2QueryExtension onActivate() : Disabled by unsupported host app
07-19 13:35:18.167  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 25264   Conv2QueryExtension Conv2Query not enabled due to current app [ir.sunn.emsbase] not in whitelist
07-19 13:35:18.167  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   Conv2QueryExtension Current locale: en_US, config allows these locales: de,en,fr,it,es,pt
07-19 13:35:18.167  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   Conv2QueryExtension isEnabled() : true
07-19 13:35:18.167  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   EmojiSuperpacksFeature  Emoji superpacks enabled
07-19 13:35:18.167  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   EmojiDataExtension  onActivate() : Locale = en_US
07-19 13:35:18.167  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 17925   monodroid-assembly  typemap: module matching MVID [CAD0FB41-A72A-4345-B6B8-DAF8486E8A76] not found.
07-19 13:35:18.167  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   DevFeatureConfig    Gif candidate disabled by Phenotype
07-19 13:35:18.167  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   GifEntryExtension   onActivate()
07-19 13:35:18.158  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 25264   VoiceImeTranscriptor    UIME feature enabled: false
07-19 13:35:18.155  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   GoogleInputMethod   onStartInputView() : Dummy InputConnection bound
07-19 13:35:18.154  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   GoogleInputMethod   onStartInput() : Dummy InputConnection bound
07-19 13:35:18.154  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 17925   monodroid-assembly  typemap: module matching MVID [CAD0FB41-A72A-4345-B6B8-DAF8486E8A76] not found.
07-19 13:35:18.153  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   PhenotypeExpConfig  refreshConfiguration() : Force = false : UpdateAvailable = false : Age = 62 minutes : MaxAge = 720 minutes
07-19 13:35:18.134  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 17925   monodroid-assembly  typemap: module matching MVID [CAD0FB41-A72A-4345-B6B8-DAF8486E8A76] not found.
07-19 13:35:18.048  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 17925   monodroid-assembly  typemap: module matching MVID [CAD0FB41-A72A-4345-B6B8-DAF8486E8A76] not found.
07-19 13:35:18.030  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    17925   mono-stdout Binding: 'Password' property not found on 'EmsBase.ViewModels.LoginViewModel', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Entry.Text'
07-19 13:35:17.871  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25132   GnssLocationProvider    WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@5ff5ba7)
07-19 13:35:17.869  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25132   GnssLocationProvider    WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@5ff5ba7)
07-19 13:35:17.626  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   FeaturePermissions  onSharedPreferenceChanged() : Key = latest_activation_time : Feature = null
07-19 13:35:17.612  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   VoiceImeExtension   Voice Extension onStartInputView() Mic status = [MicIconHidden-PasswordOrNumberOrDateInputType, ]
07-19 13:35:17.540  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 25264   VoiceImeTranscriptor    UIME feature enabled: false
07-19 13:35:17.540  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   PrimesMetrics   Ignore memory metric of com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.libs.pill.PillExtension.
07-19 13:35:17.539  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   PrimesMetrics   Ignore memory metric of com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.libs.search.nativecard.FeatureCardNoticeExtension.
07-19 13:35:17.539  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   FeatureCardNotice   Feature card notice not shown: no cards to display
07-19 13:35:17.539  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   FeatureCardGenerator    Autospace card not added
07-19 13:35:17.539  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   FeatureCardGenerator    Make a GIF card not added
07-19 13:35:17.538  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 25264   Conv2QueryExtension onActivate() : Disabled by unsupported host app
07-19 13:35:17.538  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 25264   Conv2QueryExtension Conv2Query not enabled due to current app [ir.sunn.emsbase] not in whitelist
07-19 13:35:17.537  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   Conv2QueryExtension Current locale: en_US, config allows these locales: de,en,fr,it,es,pt
07-19 13:35:17.537  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   Conv2QueryExtension isEnabled() : true
07-19 13:35:17.535  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   EmojiSuperpacksFeature  Emoji superpacks enabled
07-19 13:35:17.535  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   EmojiDataExtension  onActivate() : Locale = en_US
07-19 13:35:17.532  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   PrimesMetrics   Ignore memory metric of com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.libs.search.gif.GifEntryPointCandidateExtension.
07-19 13:35:17.531  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   DevFeatureConfig    Gif candidate disabled by Phenotype
07-19 13:35:17.531  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   GifEntryExtension   onActivate()
07-19 13:35:17.527  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 17925   monodroid-assembly  typemap: module matching MVID [CAD0FB41-A72A-4345-B6B8-DAF8486E8A76] not found.
07-19 13:35:17.519  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   DlamWrapper close(): Successfully wrote DLAM properties file.
07-19 13:35:17.514  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   LatinIme    onDeactivate()
07-19 13:35:17.514  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   Delight5Decoder abortComposing() : input state id = 401
07-19 13:35:17.513  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   LatinIme    abortComposing()
07-19 13:35:17.512  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25264   PhenotypeExpConfig  refreshConfiguration() : Force = false : UpdateAvailable = false : Age = 62 minutes : MaxAge = 720 minutes
07-19 13:35:17.509  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 25085   audio_hw_generic    Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 33246355 , only wrote 33246000
07-19 13:35:17.366  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Warning 17925   monodroid-assembly  typemap: module matching MVID [CAD0FB41-A72A-4345-B6B8-DAF8486E8A76] not found.
07-19 13:35:17.331  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    17925   mono-stdout Binding: 'Email' property not found on 'EmsBase.ViewModels.LoginViewModel', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Entry.Text'
07-19 13:35:16.868  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25132   GnssLocationProvider    WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@d45adcb)
07-19 13:35:16.867  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25132   GnssLocationProvider    WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@d45adcb)
07-19 13:35:15.870  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25132   GnssLocationProvider    WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@131909a)
07-19 13:35:15.868  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25132   GnssLocationProvider    WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@131909a)
07-19 13:35:14.869  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25132   GnssLocationProvider    WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@d1145)
07-19 13:35:14.868  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25132   GnssLocationProvider    WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@d1145)
07-19 13:35:13.867  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25132   GnssLocationProvider    WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@156cdbc)
07-19 13:35:13.866  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25132   GnssLocationProvider    WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@156cdbc)
07-19 13:35:12.867  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25132   GnssLocationProvider    WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@76e65af)
07-19 13:35:12.865  pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28    Info    25132   GnssLocationProvider    WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@76e65af)
```

Comment: can you try adding the TwoWay [BindingMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindingmode?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_BindingMode_TwoWay) to `Email` and `Password`?

Comment: @dbvega Entry will default to 2 way binding

Comment: you need to add some log messages or other debug info to capture what is happening when you are in release mode

Comment: @sunny I think the issue is the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation. Check how to create events and invoke them. Basically you need to change `PropertyChanged = delegate { };` by `PropertyChanged;` and then invoke the event using `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(...`

Comment: @dbvega  PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Password")); not work

Comment: You can also debug in the release mode and add a breakpoint at OnSubmitAsync method to check what email and passworkdis at that point.

Comment: @jack Hua in debug mode every think is good

Comment: I mean debug in the **release** mode. If everything is good, you should not get the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after 4 days, my resolver was change my assembly name from mixed lowercase and upercase to lowercase and every think work fine to this time.